# Submitting project source into Mercurial repository

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, bitbucket

I'm developing my android game since 6 months, and lately I was afraid that I could lose my source somehow, so I decided to use mercurial repository on https://bitbucket.org

But really, I'm not able to put my existing project from eclipse, into created mercurial repository, I have been googling a lot, but couldn't find any tutorial. I found this steps:

$ cd /path/to/my/repo
$ hg push https://MyName@bitbucket.org/MyName/diego

I used them using windows cmd, but doesn't work.

It says: "Name 'hg' is not recognizable as an internal or external command"

Can someone please give me some tips how to put existing eclipse project into mercurial repository, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the error message rather than just saying "doesn't work".  Have you run either `hg init` or `hg clone https://MyName@bitbucket.org/MyName/diego`?

Comment: For the record, "but doesn't work" is not very helpful at all. You'd be much better off providing us with the error you encountered.

Comment: Sorry, updated with error log.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know why I got the downvote, but updating based on new information:

Make sure you have installed mercurial (either via installer or easy_install). If you install via an installer, you must browse to the installed directory that contains the `hg.exe` binary (e.g. in the case of TortoiseHg, %Program Files%\TortoiseHg). Then add this directory to your PATH:

- Press Windows Key + Pause/Break
- Advanced > Environment Variables
- Under System Variables, find Path, and add the directory to the end, prepended with a `;` if there isnt one already.
- OK/Save

Start a new cmd.exe and see if the command `hg` works. If it doesn't it might be easier for you to install something like TortoiseHg and use the explorer context menus and GUI to do mercurial operations.

Once you get hg working, first do `hg init` in your project directory to setup the `.hg` folder. then you can `push` . You will probably want to setup `.hgignore` before you do, because eclipse can add a lot of cached metadata.

Comment: Thanks for answer, the problem is that after using hg init it says:

Name 'hg' is not recognizable as an internal or external command

Comment: @LazyBadger my response was correct based on initial information (he only put the error message up later) - the most likely assumption was that the repo wasn't initialised; considering the fact that asker was doing development for 6 months, it was fair to assume he was familiar with a command line.